# Laravel multiple hasMany

Tags: laravel, relationship

i wanna use multiple hasMany and belongsTo that subcategory uses two function, onece for return products and another once for return products with orderBy condition. how can i do that????

```
class Category extends Eloquent{
   public function product(){
      return $this->hasMany('Product');  
   }
   public function product_ordered(){
      return $this->hasMany('product')->orderBy('updated_at','DESC');
   }
}
```

and Product file:

```
class Product extends Eloquent{
   public function Category(){
      return $this->belongsTo('category');
   }
}
```

and i wanna to use both of that in different Views

view 1:

```
@foreach($category->product_ordered as $x){
   ...
}
```

view2:

```
@foreach($category->product as $x){
   ...
}
```

Thank you so much...

Comment: And what's not working with the above code?

Comment: return $this->hasMany('product')->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC');

as the argument is the name of your model class (Product), make first character uppercase

Comment: i can not use same together...

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to define the relation twice, you can make a method that accesses the first relation, then sorts it by whatever you need.

```
class Category extends Eloquent
{
   public function product(){
      return $this->hasMany('Product');  
   }

   public function product_ordered(){
      return $this->product->sortByDesc('updatedAt');
   }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your notice and answer. but it give this error:       ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\wamp\www\laravel-new\app\views\index.blade.php)